# twitter bootstrap viewport

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've inherited a set of templates for a site based on Twitter Bootstrap. In the `<head>` the following meta-tag appears:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

But according to the docs, it should be:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Can someone explain what the difference between these two is?

Answer (score 7):

They are just different properties, you can add one or more. From Mozilla's site:

> The **width** property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to a specific number of pixels like width=600 or to the special value device-width value which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a scale of 100%.

And the second one controls the zoom when the page is displayed:

> The **initial-scale** property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded.

Additionally, you can also use the **maximum-scale**, **minimum-scale**, and **user-scalable** properties to further control how users will zoom the page in or out.

This is necessary because mobile devices have very different pixel densities, so by specifying properties like these a page with will render at almost the same physical size in  iPhones, Galaxies, Nokias, etc., regardless of screen density.

[More info here (Mozilla page)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: If I omit `initial-scale=1.0"` will it default to this value, making the 2 declarations above effectively indentical?

Comment: Since the standard is not yet thoroughly defined (at least last time I checked), I imagine it depends on the implementation. For instance, mobile Safari defaults to a calculated zoom that allows fitting the webpage in the visible area. If you want to make sure just add it as well.